# Why would RSpec report multiple validation errors of the same type?

Tags: rspec-rails

The following code:

```
describe Task do
  let(:task) { Task.new }
  subject { task }
  before(:each) do
    task.valid?
    p task.errors.full_messages
  end
  it { should have(1).error_on(:title) }
  it { should have(1).error_on(:description) }
end
```

outputs: `["Title can't be blank", "Title can't be blank", "Title can't be blank"]` and I can't figure out any specific reason this would happen but the way I experiencing things is that let and subject don't work very well lol

Even the following code produces the same errors:

```
  it "should have 1 error on title" do
    Task.new.should have(1).error_on(:title)
  end

  it "should have 1 error on description" do
    Task.new.should have(1).error_on(:description)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of this issue was that some other spec was failing. When I got those specs passing this one did too. Very interesting.