# Capybara specs pass when run individually but fail when ran fail as part of a suite

Tags: selenium, capybara, rspec2, poltergeist

Anyone know any particular reason why a request spec never passes when run with `bundle exec rspec spec` but passes when run directly `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/models_spec.rb`?

I have tried the spec in both selenium and poltergeist but get the same result. When I run the whole test suite the specs fail, when I run it individually it passes.

I have a related question concerning a model spec [Why would RSpec report multiple validation errors of the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254501/why-would-rspec-report-multiple-validation-errors-of-the-same-type) that could possibly be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting but simple. Threads seems to have gotten intertwined and a button that should be saying Add was saying Manage. Temporary fix was to just delete everything from the database before running each spec.